# How do I call a real-time log simulator which gets information from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, javafx, concurrency

I'm fully aware this has been asked already, but my problem lays in *how* to call that specific function. 
So, let me introduce the main problem: I have to make a log for adding customers to queues.

I've tried several versions of methods that have runnables and Platform.runLater(...) in order to solve this problem, but it only updates the log after the process is finished. Since these kinds of methods have worked for other people, I'm beginning to think that I'm using them incorrectly. Here is what I wrote:

This is where I declared the UI, I used a Pane in which a

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scheduler.border.setCenter(Scheduler.scroll);
        Scene scene = new Scene(Scheduler.border, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        scheduler.run();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Runnable class. It displays in console every one second and the gui after 10 seconds. The second method is the one that is supposed to solve my problem: making a FX thread to allow me to change the UI. And it does, but at the wrong time.

```
class Scheduler implements Runnable{

    private static final int numberQueues = 3;
    static final int serviceTime = 10;
    static volatile int currentTime;
    public static BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    public static Pane scroll = new Pane();
    public static TextArea logList = new TextArea(" Starting Logs...\n");

    public Scheduler() {currentTime = 0;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (serviceTime > currentTime) {
            currentTime += 1;
            try {
                writeToActivityLog(currentTime + " | Customer at queue" + currentTime % numberQueues);
                System.out.println(currentTime + " | Customer at queue" + currentTime % numberQueues);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
        static public void writeToActivityLog(String logEntry){

        class Threade implements Runnable {
            private String logEntry;

            private Threade(String logEntry){
                this.logEntry = logEntry;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                logList.appendText(logEntry);
                scroll.getChildren().removeAll();
                scroll.getChildren().addAll(logList);
            }
        }
        String updatedLog = logList.getText()+ logEntry;
        Threade thread = new Threade(updatedLog);
        Platform.runLater(thread);
    }
}
```

So, as I stated before, I want to get the logs to generate as the threads run, not only after the threads are finished. But that's the only way I can get them. Also, the window freezes it's clicked during the thread process, but it's fine after the threads finish running.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and [edit] the question to include it. Currently there are too many things we do not know about to answer the question. (E.g. how much is "several per second"? How is `Executor.executeSchedule();` implemented?)

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you :) Then why don't you comply to what it suggests? Or what didn't you understand?

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, I did read it but I was pretty unsure if the pool really matters or not. I've removed some parts to see where it doesn't work and these are the only two remaining parts that can be tested for the problem. If there is anything else I can improve please tell me.

Comment: you need to provide an _example_ not snippets .. the idea  is that others can reproduce your problem by just throwing it into their IDE.

Comment: Start with having an `Application` class and a `main`, then add the relevant code. If you can't run it and see the problem so can't we.

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes and thanks for helping me out.

Comment: that's far too complicated: a) unusual as it is, let the scheduler take care of setting up the borderPane and its content b) scroll isn't used (and not necessary as textArea manages its own scrolling) with that a) boils down to adding the textArea to the center c) remove all static accessors, instead let main instantiate a scheduler and start that in a thread d) in writeToActivityLog, remove everything and add `Platform.runlater(() -> logList.appendText(logText));`

Comment: @kleopatra sorry for the late response. I've tried your suggestion and it's still only writing in real-time only in the console. What I did was instantiating scheduler in main, creating a task that runs the scheduler, and running that task in Main's start (after showing the stage). For the scheduler, I've set up the border pane in its constructor.

Comment: @kleopatra Nevermind, I accidentally used thread.run() instead of start(). It works now, thanks a lot!!